# How to move plugin link from left navigation to a different location?

Tags: dashboard, admin-menu

I have the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. How do I move the link so it's under Settings (like some other plugins) or under the Screen Options Tab? I don't want to hide it completely as I would still need to be able to use it. Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very popular plugin that gives you this ability in an easy package

[Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)